# Anyone with information on tape format used with early SunOS2.0 or how to get the data out

Tags: solaris, tape

Having located, downloaded the `.tgz` and uncompressed it, I am now faced with three directories `tape1`,`tape2`, and `tape3` with 10 or numbered bits.

Using

```
od -c
```

and

```
vi :%!xxd
```

did not produce anything like English, and this is supposed to be the source tree. Any suggestions how I can extract the contents of the tape image files please.

Comment: Maybe the `file` command will help identify what these are.

Comment: .tgz should be a compressed tar. Did it decompress without error? Did you actually extract it with tar? Where did 3 directories come from? What are "numbered bits". If you have files with names like tape1, it is quite possible that they are tars (or even compressed tars) that were wrapped in another tar layer. GNU tar will unpack older tar formats -- see the --format option. Options posix, ustar or v7 might be useful.

Comment: Maybe this question over at Server Fault can help: https://serverfault.com/questions/366571/restore-old-sunos-tapes/475723/

Comment: @Paul_Pedant GNU tar is not recommended as it's archive support is bad. better use `star` that includes more and better format support, e.g. `cpio` as well.

Comment: Can your provide a list of files? And FWIW, a tgz file almost certainly didn't originate in that form on an old Sun machine.

Comment: My target is a HDD source tree, I am not trying to build a tape image or run this code, just look at the original m68k, and SPARC  source code at the moment, and yes I know GNU stuff is incomparable with old original UNIX (however defined) and spinoffs such as BSD and SunOS and the rest.  NOTE tape1  is a directorie as is tape2, etc, the files are 01, 02 etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is a long time...

As far as I remember, the install tape #1 contains the following "files", where a "file" is data between two EOF marks on the tape. I am not 100% sure with the order and the exact tape file indices:

- a stand-alone boot with a menu on file #1
- a kernel image
- a ram disk image
- a standalone disk formatter
- one or more TAR archives with parts of the install or at least an inventory list.

In other words: if you tell the boot prom to boot from tape, if does the right things.

So what are you interested in?

If you like to analyze the tapes, I recommend to do the following:

```
mt -f /dev/rmt1n asf 1 # or a similar tape device that fits
star -tv f=/dev/rmt1n
```

Then continue with `mt afs 2 ...` until you get an error message that indicates a hard EOF on the tape. Skip tape files that are flagged by star as non-archive...

The other tapes contain more or less just one tar image.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply.  I do not have  "real" tape, just a .tgz tape that unpacked to three directories each with a series of files numbered in ascending order and of various sizes possibly individual files from the original tapes.

Comment: You did not mention what you like to do. If you like to create a QIC boot tape, you just need to `dd` the images in the right order to a QIC tape cassette using the no-rewind tape device entry.

Comment: Hi I am trying to build/regenerate  the source tree of Sunos_3.2_sun2 from the tgz tape. i successfully uncompressed the tar , into ./Sunos_3.2_sun2" what I have is  four directors ./Sunos_3.2_sun2/tape1, etc

Comment: Hi I am trying to build/regenerate  the source tree of Sunos_3.2_sun2 from the tgz tape. i successfully uncompressed the tar , into ./Sunos_3.2_sun2" what I have is  four directors ./Sunos_3.2_sun2/tape1, etc

Comment: part II of comment:       ls -R gives;            Sunos_3.2_sun2:
tape1  tape2  tape3  tape4

Sunos_3.2_sun2-tapeimgs/tape1:
01  02  03  04  05  06  07  08  09  10

Sunos_3.2_sun2-tapeimgs/tape2:
01  02  03  04  05  06  07

Sunos_3.2_sun2-tapeimgs/tape3:
01  02  03  04  05  06  07  08  09  10  11  12  13  14  15

Sunos_3.2_sun2-tapeimgs/tape4:
01  02  03  04  05  06  07  08
 file 01, gives      01: data

Comment: I have now unpacked 3 different SunOS version  tgz files, all with similar results  directories named tape1, to tape4 containing numbered files that "file" says are data.  The iso files for other version have been easy, simply mount them on /mnt and tar them off, then unpack in target pigeonhole (directory).

Comment: The information in the server link is not applicable to my situation as I am not on a Solaris or SunOS box.  I do not have tape, just a .tgz file  file from off the Internet